# How to check time on all the nodes in hadoop cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie, hue

I am running spark job on hadoop cluster, and the job is failing at few times with the exception :
exception : Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception, begin > end in range (begin, end): (1494159709088, 1494159706071)

the job ran successfully on the rerun.
After searching on google, It might be Clock skew between the Oozie server host and launcher host. 
Is there a way i can check if there is clock skew ? or how can i check the time on all the nodes whether they are in sync or not.

Thanks

ntptime command output :

```
ntp_gettime() returns code 0 (OK)
  time dcb9b19b.a2328f64  Sun, May  7 2017 14:45:47.633, (.633584090),
  maximum error 434990 us, estimated error 815 us, TAI offset 0
ntp_adjtime() returns code 0 (OK)
  modes 0x0 (),
  offset 176.871 us, frequency -25.666 ppm, interval 1 s,
  maximum error 434990 us, estimated error 815 us,
  status 0x2001 (PLL,NANO),
  time constant 10, precision 0.001 us, tolerance 500 ppm,
```

ntpstat command output :

```
synchronised to NTP server (174.68.168.57) at stratum 3 
   time correct to within 77 ms
   polling server every 1024 s
```

Comment: Look into Linux commands `ntpstat` and `ntptime`. Also, check with your SysAdmin whether the nodes are using NTPD or Chrony to sync their server clock, the sync frequency, whether there are system alerts when the clock skew goes beyond limit, etc.

Comment: Side note: the Cloudera monitoring tools control clock skew, because it's critical for some features (especially Kerberos auth)

Comment: Hey, @SamsonScharfrichter I am not sure how to check things you mentioned. I have updated the question with the output of commands ntpstat and ntptime.
Can you elaborate how to check things you mentioned ?

Comment: I checked time on all the nodes, They all seems to be same.

Comment: The question is, do the nodes *sometimes* fail to synchronize their clocks often enough, so that *sometimes* they drift too far from other nodes? or so that *sometimes* the next sync results in the clock going back in time?

Comment: I think the nodes sometimes fail to synchronize their clocks.
As when i validated the clocks were in sync.
Is there any other reason to happen this ?